# Local variable not accessible inside callback - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code snippet.

```
var mapping  = {};
_.each(labels,function(i,label){
    debugger;
});
```

but mapping variable is not accessible inside the function.

I have a similar code somewhere else

```
var labels = {};
_.each(arrOfFields, function(element,index){
    labels[prefix+element.fcnbb] = element.UI.label;
});
```

and labels is accessible here and i am able to use it.

Please explain me why does this happen ??

Comment: how do you determine that `mapping` is not available inside the function? Have you tried to actually use it? and your functions argument order is wrong, `_.each()` ain't jquery.

Comment: I'm assuming _.each() is underscore.js. I tried your top snippet and was able to access the mapping variable inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here that **mapping** variable isn't declare within the function code block.

In debug mode if you used a callback function like in here you need to declare it within the function, so debugger will save it as his local variable.

so:

```
var mapping  = {};
_.each(labels,function(i,label){
    console.log(mapping);  // here
    debugger;
});
```

Just write variable name even in `console.log()` function, the debug will know his local variables, and then you will have an access to the variable itself.